# Python List Comprehension With List of List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of list (Actual list is longer):

```
a = [[1, 2], [5, 8], [10, 4], [15, 9]]
```

I need to use this list in list comprehension. For the first loop 1 and 2 will be used as i and j. For the second loop 5 and 8 will be used as i and j. And so on.

Following code is not correct, but how can I make it work? I do not want to split the list. Very very little computational cost is important.

```
[some_work_with(i, j) for i, j in zip(a[][0], a[][1])]
```

Some work could be `print(i, j)`.

Comment: `[some_work_with(i, j) for i, j in a]`? If `a` is already a list of 2-tuples or 2-lists, then there's no need to use `zip()` on it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `zip` here, just unpack the elements as you are iterating over them

```
[some_work_with(i, j) for i, j in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(i,j):
    return [i-1, j+1]

a = [[1, 2], [5, 8], [10, 4], [15, 9]]

print ([func(x[0], x[1]) for x in a])
```

Output:

```
[[0, 3], [4, 9], [9, 5], [14, 10]]
```

You can also use this syntax if you prefer:

```
print ([func(i, j) for i, j in a])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```py
[some_work(pair[0], pair[1]) for pair in a]
```

for example

```py
[f'i : {pair[0]} and j : {pair[1]}' for pair in a]
```

This will result in:

```
['i : 1 and j : 2', 'i : 5 and j : 8', 'i : 10 and j : 4', 'i : 15 and j : 9']
```